# Convert RTF to JPEG

Tags: c#, rtf, gembox-document

I have a RTF file as in this image
[image]

I converted from RTF to JPEG with this code using the GemBox component

```
DocumentModel document = new DocumentModel();
        document = DocumentModel.Load("1.rtf");
        document.Save("Convert.Jpeg");
```

However, the output file did not preserve the original column witdh (see image)
[image]

Comment: Can you use [this link](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support-center/new-ticket) and submit a support ticket to us (GemBox Software Support) and attach the "1.rtf" file to your ticket. We'll reproduce your issue and investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AutoFit` feature
[Here some example from docs](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-excel-row-column-autofit/108)

Comment: tnks but this sample is for Excel File

Comment: that way try to use this manual with `PreferredWidth` http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/SampleExplorer/Document/Table/TableFormatting?tab=cs

Comment: i nead find table and foreach on table but i cant find tables on document